# UIDocumentInteractionController: (null) image

Tags: ios, nsurl, uidocumentinteraction

I'm downloading an image from API and saving it to a directory on the device. Then I'm trying to use UIDocumentInteractionController on it, passing on the local path of image I just saved.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath];
UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: url];
interactionController.delegate = self;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
[interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

When I compare two NSString by logging, this is what I get:

- `[url absoluteString]`

  `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1121F345-0BCA-4624-8A72-F4CE0D39EAE5/Documents/complaint/1443432747ea3dc39ca0b2f6b5f17abddec1f0e9a439955.png`
- `filePath`

  `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1121F345-0BCA-4624-8A72-F4CE0D39EAE5/Documents/complaint/1443432747ea3dc39ca0b2f6b5f17abddec1f0e9a439955.png`

As you can tell, the path is indentical, apart from file:// at the beginning or url string. The image isn't corrupted, yet in every action picked from UIDocumentInteractionController (saving image, assigning it to contact, etc) there is a (null) object instead of the Image.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

If I use

```
[interactionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

instead of

```
[interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

And provide delegate method `documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:` image displays and all actions work.
Why does it work when used with preview, but not without it?

Comment: Are you storing the whole path ? Can you show how you created `filePath` ?

Comment: It's rather complicated, because I keep many directories in my Documents (I made helper methods), but the filePath is correct: I am able succesfully perform `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile` with it.

Comment: Add the code where you read "(null) object instead of the Image" from `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Comment: It's a log message appearing after picking 'Assign to contact' option. `Couldn't get file size for (null): (null)` . The image doesn't appear during this operation.

Comment: Did you get the solution for it?

Answer (score 4):

I found my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102181/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-for-open-in-menu-doesnt-work).

Basically the `UIDocumentInteractionController` was deallocated (ARC) before the selected action could be processed. Make sure it is retained, I did that by creating a `strong` property for it (`strong` is default for the example below).

```
@property (nonatomic) UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController;
```

Comment: This has been exactly my problem. Thanks.